# Codeigniter Server timeout - Running bulk DB queries inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, foreach

I have a database query written inside a foreach loop, where in some cases the query is executed more than 100 times with different parameters.

The script runs fine when the foreach loop is repeated only few rounds.

Instead of rearranging the query to fetch all data in a single request is there any other alternative that I can run the script with the foreach loop in an efficient way?

My current script

```
//  some where clauses here
$re = $this->db->get('cash_collection')->result();
    
$d=0;
foreach($re as $area){   // this loop runs 100+ rounds
    // call a function with single db query
    $re[$d]->area_paid = $this->Payment_m->get_inTotalForNormal($area->fka_id,$area->in_date);
    $d++;
}       
return $re;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your need, I think you need to replace "**result()**" with "**unbuffered_row()**". The result() will load the whole result into memory at once, while the [unbuffered_row()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=unbuffered#CI_DB_result::unbuffered_row) method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole result in memory. You can learn more [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=unbuffered#CI_DB_result::unbuffered_row).

Example Code

```
//  some where clauses here
$re = $this->db->get('cash_collection');
    
$d=0;
while ($area = $query->unbuffered_row()) {   // this loop runs 100+ rounds
    // call a function with single db query
    $re[$d]->area_paid = $this->Payment_m->get_inTotalForNormal($area->fka_id,$area->in_date);
    $d++;
}       
return $re;
```

Now your script should be able to handle large result sets.

Note for **CI4** it is **getUnbufferedRow()**.

Comment: Thanks mail2bapi for the reply. In my case your solution didn't work. Instead I used get_compiled_select(); method to merge queries together and it brought down the time from 78s to 3seconds